# This command is not working : npm install --save-dev node--sass@4.7.2

Tags: npm

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node--sass - Notfound
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'node--sass@4.7.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name 
   yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HARIKA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05- 
       27T19_25_06_044Z-debug.log

C:\Users\HARIKA\Desktop\bootstrapassign1\Bootstrap4\conFusion>node-v 'node-v' 
is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or 
batch file.
```

I am getting this above error while installing `node-sass` into my windows7 using the command `npm install --save-dev node--sass@4.7.2`.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Node are you using? try `npm update node-sass@latest`  or check this link: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2

Comment: The version is  v12.16.3

Comment: So you mean according to the link the version d 4.7.2 of sass is not support by the node version of  v12.16.3

Comment: Check Nicholas Carey answer, LOL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try reading the error message that NPM is logging:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node--sass - Notfound
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'node--sass@4.7.2' is not in the npm registry.
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're trying to install a package named `node--sass` which doesn't exist in NPM, rather than the desired package, `node-sass`, which **does** exist in NPM.

Comment: Right! Common mistake in programming, assuming what it says

Comment: But Nicholas Carey I just wrote the command npm install --save-dev node-sass@4.7.2

Comment: C:\Users\HARIKA\Desktop\bootstrapassign1\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_
modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN confusion@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.